# MongoDB, how to use document as the smallest unit to search the document in array?

Tags: mongodb

Sorry for the title, but I really do not know how to make it clear. But I can show you.

Here I have insert two document

```
> db.test.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("557faa461ec825d473b21422"),
    "c" : [
        {
            "a" : 3,
            "b" : 7
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("557faa4c1ec825d473b21423"),
    "c" : [
        {
            "a" : 1,
            "b" : 3
        },
        {
            "a" : 5,
            "b" : 9
        }
    ]
}
>
```

I only want to select the first document with a value which is greater than 'a' and smaller than 'b', like '4'.

But when i search, i cannot get the result i want

```
> db.test.find({'c.a': {$lte: 4}, 'c.b': {$gte: 4}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("557faa461ec825d473b21422"), "c" : [ { "a" : 3, "b" : 7 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("557faa4c1ec825d473b21423"), "c" : [ { "a" : 1, "b" : 3 }, { "a" : 5, "b" : 9 } ] }
>
```

Because '4' is greater than the '"a" : 1' and smaller than '"b" : 9' in the second document even it is not in the same document in the array, so the second one selected.

But I only want the first one selected.

I found this http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch, but it seems the example is not suitable for my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to

```
db.test.findOne({ c: {$elemMatch: {a: {$lte: 4}, b: {$gte: 4} } } })
```

With your query, you are searching for documents that have an object in the 'c' array that has a key 'a' with a value <= 4, and a key 'b' with a value >= 4.

The second record is return because c[0].a is <= 4, and c[1].b is >= 4.

Since you specified you wanted to select only the first document, you would want to do a findOne() instead of a find().

Answer (score 0):

Use [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) as below :

```
db.test.find({"c":{"$elemMatch":{"a":{"$lte":4},"b":{"$gte":4}}}})
```

Or

```
db.test.find({"c":{"$elemMatch":{"a":{"$lte":4},"b":{"$gte":4}}}},{"c.$":1})
```